# Input and output files from a dictionary in Snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to create a Snakemake workflow that will take a dictionary with a predefined mapping between input and output files. Below is my attempt at it, but I am getting KeyError with 'file_out=1.txt'. I don't understand why file_out can take that value, since it is not a key in the dictionary.

```
MAP = {"2.txt": "1.txt", "3.txt": "2.txt", "4.txt": "3.txt"}

def map_link(wildcards):
    fname = MAP[wildcards.file_out]
    return(fname)

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{file_out}", file_out=list(MAP.keys()))
    
rule map:
    input:
        map_link
    output:
        "{file_out}"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```

I've also tried ChatGPT for this, but it was going nowhere. That's its example attempt:

```
MAP = {"2.txt": "1.txt", "3.txt": "2.txt", "4.txt": "3.txt", "5.txt": "4.txt"}

rule map:
    input:
        MAP["{output}"]
    output:
        "{output}"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"

rule all:
    input:
        list(MAP.keys())
```

Also getting KeyError ('{output}') which probably means that wildcards can't be initiated in the output directive.

The final goal is to be able to specify using csv file all three: script (that makes one or more files), input file(s) and predefined (by scripts) outputs files that could be used by other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet is correct, but there is no way for `snakemake` to build file `1.txt` as there is no key with such name in the `MAP` dictionary. That's why the `KeyError` is raised.

If file `1.txt` is the only input file that exists, there still needs to be a way for snakemake to check its dependency. Running your code with the following `MAP` (assuming `1.txt` exists) will execute without errors:

```py
MAP = {"2.txt": "1.txt", "3.txt": "2.txt", "4.txt": "3.txt", "1.txt": "0.txt"}
```

Note that it doesn't matter if you put anything else in place of "0.txt", the only purpose of that key-value pair is to make sure that the function executes `map_link` without error.

Alternatively, you can modify `map_link` to return an empty string when a key is not defined:

```py
def map_link(wildcards):
    fname = MAP.get(wildcards.file_out, "")
    return fname
```

The above function will work with the original `MAP` dictionary.

The second snippet is almost correct, the `input` directive needs to be turned into a lambda expression:

```py
rule map:
    input:
        lambda wildcards: MAP.get(f"{wildcards.output}", "")
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! `1.txt` is the only input file that exists at the time of workflow execution.
Your solution for the second snippet also generates KeyError `Error: KeyError: '{wildcards.output}'
Wildcards:  output=2.txt`

Comment: Yes, the string in brackets should be f-string: `MAP[f"{wildcards.output}"]`.

Comment: Now it converged to the same error as my solution: KeyError with `1.txt` as key

Comment: Amazing, that (modifying map_link) works! Thank you for your help, @SultanOrazbayev!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand where you are going with this from the description you provide, and this setup with a recursive use of the same mapping dictionary does not look like something you want to do with Snakemake. I would usually at least expect a fixed file extension outside of a rules output wildcards.

But from looking at your particular error message, I am assuming that you do not have the file `1.txt` present. So snakemake tries to generate it, by plugging it into the `output: "{file_out}"` wildcard and then the lookup in the `MAP` obviously fails. If `1.txt` is present in the directory that you run your workflow, it should simply find it and not try to produce it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! File `1.txt` is, indeed, present in the directory where the Snakefile is. Apologies I didn't make my final goal clear. In a nutshell, the idea is to create a single workflow that will be mostly defined by csv file content, including variable scripts that use inputs to produce outputs (hence output file extention may be different)

Comment: But then, each script should have its own `rule` and defined inputs and outputs, which is the very purpose of snakemake. I just can't really see a practival scenario where this `dict` mapping construct is useful and just from looking at it, I think it will quickly complicate readability of your workflow. The map will quickly end up in a different place from the rule in a larger workflow, and thus become hard to find. I would suggest to start working on your actual intended workflow, creating it rule by rule.

Comment: I fully understand that it is not what snakemake makers had in mind! Just trying to add a level of abstraction, where one/two rules could be reused to dynamically create a workflow based on a simple csv file.
Sounds like a wrapper script that would produce a regular snakefile off a csv file is the approach to take here. Thank you for your help!